# Hiding focusability on start

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, focus

In my sign in activity I added a method that set a border for the edit text if it is focusable so that the user can know that he is entering data in this field and the border will be highlighted...but when the activity start, the method directly is applied on the first username edit text knowing that I'm hiding the keyboard...I want this method to work when the keyboard appears not before.Thank you of helping me...This is my code

Java

```
public class FoodSafetyLogIn extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_safety_log_in);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.t1_layout);

    //Hide Keyboard
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_username);
    focus(username);
    EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password);
    focus(password);
    password.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_back) {
        Intent i = new Intent(FoodSafetyLogIn.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        overridePendingTransition(R.animator.slide_in_right,R.animator.slide_in_right);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void OnClick(View view){

}

public void focus(View view){
    view.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus)
               v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.focus_border_style);
            else
               v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary);
        }
    });
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <EditText
    your edit text... />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this tag in your EditView

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```